# Counting words and letters in google chrome extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I decided to make my own google chrome extensions.

I am attempting to count the words and letters in a text provided by the user.

For some reason, when I click count, I don't see any output

There are no syntax errors in my code(checked using brackets debugger), just some logic error

This is my manifest.json file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Count Words In Text",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to count words in given input",
  "version": "0.0",
  "icons": {"128":"icon.png"},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Count Text!"
  },
  "permissions": [
  ]
}
```

This is My HTML file, popup.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Count Text!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #container {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
    -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>TEXT COUNTER</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <input type="text" id="a" value=""></input><br>
<button onclick="words()">Count!</button><br>
<input type="text" value="" id="b"></input>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And This is my javascript file, As you may know I cant use inline scripting in html, so i have to make a separate JS file

```
   /*global document*/
function words(){
var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = a.split(" ");
var c = a.split("");
var d = b.length;
var e = c.length;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="Number of Letters: "+e+"\n"+"Number of Words: "+d;
}
```

The layout, etc of the elements are correct, it's just the functionality which doesn't work...It seems like my function doesn't even get called, please inform if there are any solutions. Thank you

Edit:
I just found this on the console, Thanks to        @Titus
"Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Comment: "doesn't work" is so easy to debug

Comment: 1. change to ("b").value instead of innerHTML. 2. change to ` <textarea id="b"></textarea>` if you want the \n to work

Comment: Nope...It is still not outputting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You yourself acknowledge that you cannot use inline script, but you use:

```
<button onclick="words()">
```

That is inline script.
Change that for

```
<button id="myButton">
```

And add this into your **popup.js** file:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = words;
```

Also, move the `<script src="popup.js">` tag to the bottom of the `<body>`, to be parsed at the end.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan Nokonoko, My popup has improved, but there is still a problem, It executes the function before clicking the button even though there is an onclick event handler, and When I give it some input, It doesnt update the element with id b

Comment: Make sure you write `document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = words;` **without parenthesis after words** (that is, don't write `onclick = words()`.

Comment: Thank you So much, It works now

Comment: Happy to help. As soon as you can, remember to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

The element with ID `b` is an input, you should use:

```
document.getElementById("b").value = ....
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = ...
```

Comment: It is still not working... There is no output at the other input(with id b)

Comment: @Or.K I just gave it a try and it works for me. Is the `popup.js` file in the root directory of the extension ? Do you see any errors in the console ? You can open the *dev tools* by right clicking the extension's pop-up window and selecting **Inspect**.

Comment: I have popup.js in my root directory, I don't see any errors in the console, I opened dev tools for the exetension and i cant find any errors, btw which editor are you using?

Comment: @Or.K How did you opened the *dev tools* ? The extension has multiple contexts, if you've opened *dev tools* by selecting the extension's **background page** option you won't see the output of the pop-up.

Comment: Yes I got what you are saying, I clicked on the icon, went to Developer Tools but I can still see no output

Comment: Oh!, I Got what you are saying, in console it says,<br>"Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Comment: @Or.K Yes. I've missed that. Doing what Iván Nokonoko mentioned should fix the problem.